# Error: Unhandled Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: r, shiny

I am loading one of the example apps from Shiny R into ShiniApps.io`

```
library(shinyapps)
shinyapps::setAccountInfo(name='xxx', token='xxx', secret='xxx')
deployApp("01_hello")
```

and then I get this error:

> Error: Unhandled Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

The app appeared in the [web-page of Shinyapps.io](https://cmora.shinyapps.io/02_text) as "undeployed".

Any clue what may be causing this error? the error is the same whether I run R 64 or 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I wasn't able to successfully deploy a new app (getting the same error), but I was able to redeploy a previous app.

I have tried removing all packages and code from my new app (left only empty shinyServer and shinyUI functions uncommented) and still couldn't deploy.
Restarted R several times. Updated all packages. Nothing helped.

A few hours later I tried to deploy again and it passed without errors.

I know this is not exactly an answer but I suspect it was a server-side error because it failed during the "Starting instances" step of deployment.

So try to deploy it again, hope it works this time.

Comment: It seems it has been reported to the shinyapps mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/T0VEoSTrTAU which is the correct thing to do when you see this kind of errors.